# Async call in angular 6 API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I did below code in my API file but I don't understand how to manage below two async calls to execute the function in order can someone help me to resolve the issue or can I use promise to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
function getDataFromBK() {
  connection((db) => {

    var comment = "";
    db.collection('comment')
      .find({
        "appNo": appNo
      }, {
        "filename": fileName
      })
      .toArray()
      .then((filelist) => {
        /* response.data = filelist;
         res.json(response);*/

        comment = filelist[0].comment;
        console.log("comment-->" + comment);

        return comment;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("err-->" + err);

        return err;
      })
  });


  filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads/output/' + req.body.appNo) + '/' + req.body.filename[i];
  fileInfo.push({
    "originalName": req.body.filename[i],
    //"size": req.body.filename.size,
    "b64": new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(filepath)).toString("base64"),
    "comment": comment
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the question actually?

Comment: I want to use both calls in one function & the response of the first call I want to use in the second call.

Comment: This looks like a NodeJS and MongoDB question to me.

Comment: yes correct I am using mongo with node

Comment: Which version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: v8.11.1 is it having any impact of version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `comment` is set inside `then`, you can't expect it to be available where you're doing `fileInfo.push` as the `find` operation is going to be `async` in nature.

Try restructuring your code like this:

```
function getDataFromBK() {
  connection((db) => {

    var comment = "";

    db.collection('comment')
      .find({ "appNo": appNo }, { "filename": fileName })
      .toArray()
      .then(filelist => {

        comment = filelist[0].comment;

        filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads/output/' + req.body.appNo) + '/' + req.body.filename[i];
        fileInfo.push({
          "originalName": req.body.filename[i],
          "b64": new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(filepath)).toString("base64"),
          "comment": comment
        });



      })
      .catch(err => err)
  });
}
```